# UML: Should an asynchronous request-response message exchange be modelled as two ports/interfaces or one

Tags: interfaces, uml, modeling, asynchronous-programming

I want to model an asynchronous request-response message exchange in UML.

The request is sent from a client to a server. The server responses asynchronously.

This can be modelled in a component model in two ways:

**Option 1**

[image: Option 1]

Request and response are two different interfaces with one method each. The server provides the request interface while the client provides the reponse interface. The interfaces are required vice versa. In UML I would model the server and the client as components having one port each. Both ports expose two interfaces: a provided one and a required one which are linked from client to server (request) and from server to client (response).

**Option 2**

[image: Option 2]

Request and response is one interface with one method. The response is simply the return value of this method. The server provides and the client requires this interface. The message exchange is modelled as link from the client to the server.

I think option (1) is more appropriated for asynchronous exchanges while option (2) is the preferred way for synchronous ones. However, making such a distinction would expose a detail in the component model which actually belongs to the behavioural diagrams.

- Is there any standard or "best practice" to model an asynchronous message exchange in component models?
- If option (2) is the "right" way to do it: how should one specifiy that the client must comply with an interface contract in order to receive a response?

Comment: IMO, unless you are going to jump through all the hoops to attempt to create executable models then your diagram is supposed to help explain how the system works. Thus, it seems obvious to me that initiating commands and their responses are most easily understood when in the same diagram.  How you implement that in code is another matter entirely which depends on your architectural design. A single method call with the response as the result means the caller is going to block. This may or may not be desirable in your system.

Comment: @Dunk I added two UML diagrams to illustrate my question: it is within **one** diagram

Comment: I don't think this changes the edvice though, unless you are trying to produce an executable model then it only depends on what you want the diagram to show. Consider why are you producing this diagram in the first place? who is it for? what inormation do they want from it?

Comment: I can't say that I've used the component model for these types of diagrams. And in looking at the diagrams, I can say that I never will. Where's the value over sequence diagrams? You are eventually going to create a sequence diagram covering the same information. It seems like double work to me. What am I missing? Anyways, I use option 1 in my sequence diagrams.

Comment: @Dunk the diagram is a simplified view of course. Usually there are lots of components and the component diagram depicts the **structural** view of the systems. Sequence diagrams blow up with far less components and depict the **behaviour** of the system. Both diagrams have a different goal and a right on their own, IMHO.

Comment: @Claude - I don't want to sound antagonistic because I am not trying to be. I am truly trying to understand your thinking because maybe I will learn something. With that said: I see how the different diagrams could have different goals but with the example, what useful information do you hope to convey with the component diagram that wouldn't be more usefully conveyed in a sequence, collaboration or even activity diagram? By "useful" I am referring to being of benefit to the designer/programmer. (ie. the people that will actually use the diagrams)

Comment: @Dunk (Part1) Let me explain why I think the above diagrams might be helpful. A component (CMP) diagram displays the structural relations between CMPs. A CMP might have ports which help too to vizualize realations especially if they are repeated in a composition structure diagram displaying the inner structure of the CMP. A port may provide and/or require interfaces. For an example see [http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams-reference.html](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams-reference.html). Especially look for the "ball and socket" notation. TBC

Comment: @Dunk (Part2) A request (actually a behaviour) needs an established structural relation between client (C) and server (S). S must provide an interface which is required by C (s. option 2). In a synchronous request S simply returns the result. As a software component it doesn't need a reference to C. However, if the request is asynchronous (e.g. using an enterprise service bus) S must know (at least temporary) to whom it should send the response (Callback Interface). S requires an interface and C provides it. It's all about structure, not behaviour. The behaviour must be specified separately.

Comment: @Dunk (Part 3) Example code for a synchronous request: `interface Server { public int request(int x) }`. Example code for an asynchronous request: `interface Callback { public void response(int x) }; interface Server { public void request(int x, Callback c) }`.

Comment: @Dunk (Part 4) "Useful" ... in some projects component diagrams are simply required and you have to provide one. This diagram must be consistent with all other diagrams ... and in an asynchronous message exchange the client **must** provide an interface. However, see the [accepted answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/301176/84309) for a resolution. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are correct in the assessment that option 2 is better for synchronous messages and option 1 for asynchronous messages.

By their very nature asynchronous messaging schemes (even if it is solicited) are more complicated to model. Option 1 would be the better option to model the messaging you describe.

I appreciate your concern that using option 1 would include a fair level of detail that may be too much for the diagram in question.

You could model a *custom* relationship or association (named appropriately, e.g.: `<<CustomRqRs>>`) and use that to link the components. This simplifies the diagram, better describes the interaction and offers better modelling of the message and response itself.

---

When modelling it is always important to bear in mind that it is primarily there to communicate intent; design, usage, possible implementation, function etc. *Simpler is almost always better*. Model it accurately, model it well, but keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I resolved this issue by getting rid of the exposed interfaces. Instead of I linked both ports with a bidirectional link.